# Framing panoramic photo with caption

Tags: framing

We have a photo of myself and my partner on the salt flats in Bolivia - I’d like to frame it but with a caption in the lower border. It’s a large photo and would suit a panoramic type frame.

Ideally the frame would have large top and bottom borders with the caption in the bottom one.

I’ve searched all over looking for somewhere we can upload the image and include the caption but so far have come up empty.

Any suggestions as to an online or in store place we could get this done?

Comment: How long is the caption?

Comment: I think it would just be “Salar de Uyuni, Bolivia. 15/10/2012”

Comment: @Corey  I think we’d like it typed - though I appreciate calligraphy would look good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When framing pictures, if you plan on using glass, you absolutely must mat the photo using [mat board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat_(picture_framing)). This is because an emulsion pressed straight to the glass will tend to, especially in humid environments, adhere to the glass.

Side note: Please allow your printed photos time to air out before placing behind glass as well, as the dyes do "breathe" and can adhere to the glass if you print and frame immediately.

A signed mat board is somewhat commonplace now for [wedding photos](https://www.google.com/search?q=signed%20wedding%20mat&safe=active&client=safari&rls=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivisOriprbAhWK21MKHa6oC-AQsAQIkgE&biw=1264&bih=791).

Now, for something more professional looking, you can run a mat board through a printer (be warned, you need a printer that can run paper through flat and it may take a *lot* of trial and error to figure out profiles).

Hiring someone adept at calligraphy is also an option, as is using a set of stamps (a-la letterpress printing). A custom decal or sticker could also be used.

IMO - the best looking option is calligraphy.

Now, if you want to go *super* cheap - you can load your image into Photoshop or Gimp and create a [fake mat and add the text to it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxvpEXlQgVs). Have the whole thing printed and framed (don't use glass for reasons above).

I've done a lot of faux mats for budget high school senior photos. Some can look pretty good. But, they simply can't touch a physically matted and framed, museum glassed photo.

Comment: thanks for this - great explanation. I'll get the photo developed and use a mat board and either go the calligraphy route it or sit another printed piece of card for the caption.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty much anywhere that will print large-format by simply creating the borders and caption in an image editing program.

Personally, I think framing the image with matting and mounting the caption separately looks nicer — an integrated caption looks more like a lower-cost poster print.

Comment: I am 100% design challenged so I'll take any advice on what looks best! However I have no idea what matting is!?